# How to merge two ext4 partitions, when there is an unallocated space between them?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, gparted, ext4

I have two ext4 partitions:

- `/dev/sda6` is the one on which I have my Ubuntu right now,
- `/dev/sda5` is a recently created empty ext4 partition.

How to merge them so the data will not be lost?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean to combine them without moving or copying files, or just delete one & enlarge the other?

Answer (score 1):

Since `/dev/sda5` is first in disk order, the order of operations should be:

1. Delete `/dev/sda5`, so it becomes part of the unallocated space
2. Move `/dev/sda6` so its starting point is as much up as possible,
   which is where `/dev/sda5` used to be, so that the unallocated space now
   follows it
3. Resize `/dev/sda6` to the maximum possible so it now includes the whole
   of the unallocated space.

I suggest first to take a backup image of the whole disk, because even the smallest
mistake may destroy it.

One tool you may use is [gparted](https://gparted.org/).
Boot its
[Live CD/USB](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)
for these operations.

Answer (score 0):

Backup and data in sda6, delete sda6, expand sda5, restore data from deleted sda5 to the newly expanded sda6.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

- go to disks
- unmount your sda5 partition
- click the gear icon (additional partition options)
- click resize and drag the bar till Minimal size and select resize
- now unallocated space is created
- go to gparted and right click sda6 and select resize/move
- drag the bar to the maximum of unallocated space, click resize, ok
- its done, now accept the changes by clicking the green tick mark.